# "Finish off" or "finish off before"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, colloquial-language

Let's say you are READING AT THE MOMENT, but you are PLANNING TO PLAY a computer game (Starcraft).

> 1) 'I just have to *finish* this article *off* **first** before I play
>   Starcraft.

Or

> 2) 'I just have to *finish* this article *off* before I play Starcraft.'

NOTE: Google said, ''***finish off***'' or '***finish sth off***' is the last thing/activity you want to finish *before* you do another. **BUT**, as you can see I have included ''first''--to add clarity stating the sequence of my action. Although I am not sure, and this is not based on grammar rules, because I haven't come across this one yet, that is why I am asking.

Which is more grammatical #1 or #2?

Comment: I would not use "finish off this article" to mean finish reading.  To me, "finish off" connotes the completion of a thing you are either making or destroying; so if you said that you need to "finish off" an article, I'd assume that you were writing it, not reading it.

Comment: Hello there, how about ''I just have to finish reading this article off before I play Starcraft.'? (Hmm, seems like I have to put specific verbs in a sentence) is that ok now?

Comment: Just leave out the "off" altogether:  "I have to finish reading this article before I play Starcraft."  You might possibly use "finish off" if the article is a reading assignment (in that sense you are "terminating" the obligation to read it), but even then I'd say, "I have to finish off my homework before I play Starcraft," because the thing you're terminating is the assignment to read the article, not the article itself.

Comment: There is something missing that I wanted to clarify but I can't explain it. I get what you are trying to say. 'Finish off'=termination of something(activity/obligation) completely right? What if, I change it into 'finish up', would that be still a similar case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#2 is better. Saying "first before" is redundant: if you say you have to finish the article off *first*, then it's implied that you're doing that *before* playing the game. And vice versa. Either "First" or "before", but not both.

Honestly, you could simplify it even further, by replacing "finish off" with just "finish":

1. "I just have to finish this article, before I play StarCraft."
2. "I need to finish this article first, then I can play StarCraft."

Comment: Your #2 is like already at my disposal, and thx to you I have re-capped it, I will use it for future stuff. However, 'finish off' is a new thing for me and I wanna use it--- to add emphasis. Of course I'm gonna use the 'finish' only, but when things are a little bit hectic(like a busy workload) I think 'finish off, would be better. Hope you're catching my drift here man.